# Ajaxcontroltoolkit TextBox changes the input text (charset)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

sorry for my bad english!

I have the Ajaxcontroltoolkit TextBox (Html Editor), that changes charset in the input box.

Example:

Input string - ❝ ❞ ❛ ❜ ‘ ’ ‛ ‚ “ ” „ ‟ « » ‹ › Ꞌ " < > @ × ‧ ¨ ․ ꞉ : ⁂ ! ‼

Output string - ❝ ❞ ❛ ❜ ‘ ’ ‛ ‚ “ ” „ ‟ � � ‹ › Ꞌ " < > @ � ‧ � ․ ꞉ : ⁂ ! ‼

I have a popup window, where i do validate input text for length. And when i click Ok button -  Textbox changes the text.

Could you help me, please?

Text Box in ascx

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="OutageEndDateTextBox" Enabled="<%# OperationMode == Mode.Add || OperationMode == Mode.Edit %>" MaxLength="25" CssClass="textbox" />
```

The procedure for button OK

```
    protected void OnOkButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       modalPopup.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NoUnicode=true**

```
 <HTMLEditor:Editor runat="server" ID="CommentHTMLEditor" 
    Height="275px" Width="100%" 
    NoUnicode=true
    Enabled="<%# OperationMode == Mode.Add || OperationMode == Mode.Edit %>" />
```